# How to achieve magga nana?

Tags: theravada, personal-experience

During meditation practice have experienced mind was stopped. But some says it is samadi,not the magga phala.but now I don't have  thoughts  over myself. They say magga phala is shut down  .so what is shut down mean?

Answer (score 0):

Better to refer Sattavisuddhi in Visuddhimagga. It is the classical book of reference. Therein many characteristics of magga-phala and the way to achieve them is extensively described.

Comment: Please add some examples.